# How to correctly execute .sh file?

Tags: shell-script

I Have the .sh file with code:

```
#!/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/mayapy

python /srv/home/ApplicationName2.0/console/run_console.py
```

what I'm trying to do is to run `run_console.py` file using custom python interpreter - `mayap`. This interpreter lives in `usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/`. When I call `run_console.py` it runs using OS default python interpreter. I need to run it with `mayapy`. I already have working this script in windows using .bat file

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\mayapy.exe" %~run_console.py
```

I need to do the same in Gnu/Linux.

Comment: It is not clear what you did. Show what you did and what error was from what.

Comment: @iRex, what is `mayapy`?

Comment: It is Autodesk Maya's custom python interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The correct way

1. Remove the `.sh` and `.py` from the file-names.
2. Start the shell script with `#!/bin/bash`
3. Start the python script with `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `2` it depends. Or maybe `#!/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/mayapy` if that is a python interpreter.
4. Do `chmod +x my_python_script my_shell_script`
5. Realise that you probably don't need a shell script of one line, and run the python script directly.

## Your problem

You seem to be trying to use a python interpreter as a shell-script interpreter.

Comment: One thing that is not clear is, why do you need to run `python /srv/home/ApplicationName2.0/console/run_console.py` inside a script, if it's a single command? What's the importance for you to type `./script.sh` instead of `/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/mayapy /srv/home/ApplicationName2.0/console/run_console.py`, or even just `./run_console.py` if that is script is set up to allow it?

Comment: Also note I said remove the `.sh` and `.py` from the end of the file-name. It does not affect how it work, but it is the proper way. That way you are not leaking implementation detail (you program is contained). If you need to wrap a python script in a shell script, what concern is it of those that call upon your program?